# How to achieve multi tenancy on spring flux with kotlin coroutine?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, reactor

Sorry for my english.

I'm new in spring and kotlin.
The problem i tried to solve is getting tenant value inside kotlin coroutine. 
I made simple example https://github.com/cardid-zz/spring-multitenant-test

I have TenantContext class which holding passed tenant value

```
@Component
object TenantContext {
    const val DEFAULT: String = "default"

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    private val currentTenant = InheritableThreadLocal<String?>()

    fun getTenant() : String {
        return currentTenant.get() ?: DEFAULT
    }
    fun set(tenantId : String) {
        currentTenant.set(tenantId)
    }
    fun remove() {
        currentTenant.remove()
    }

    fun asContextElement(): ThreadContextElement<String?> {
        logger.debug("[d] asContextElement ${getTenant()}")
        return currentTenant.asContextElement(getTenant())
    }
}
```

Tenant value sets in filter

```
@Component
class TenantFilter (
    private val tenantContext: TenantContext
) : WebFilter {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    private val tenantHeader = "tenant"

    override fun filter(
        serverWebExchange: ServerWebExchange,
        webFilterChain: WebFilterChain
    ): Mono<Void> {
        val tenant = serverWebExchange.request.headers[tenantHeader]

        if (tenant.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            setTenant(TenantContext.DEFAULT)
        } else {
            setTenant(tenant.first())
        }
        logger.debug("[d] currentThread =  ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange)
    }

    private fun setTenant(tenant: String) {
        try {
            tenantContext.set(tenant)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException()
        }
    }
}
```

In controller i have two endpoints

```
@RestController
class RestController(
    private val service: SomeService
) {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    @PostMapping("/working")
    suspend fun working(@RequestParam("param") param : Int) : ResponseEntity<*> = coroutineScope(){
        val res = async{ service.doSomething(param)}
        return@coroutineScope ResponseEntity.ok(res)
    }

    @PostMapping("/failed")
    suspend fun failed(@RequestBody body: BodyParam) : ResponseEntity<*> = coroutineScope(){
        logger.debug("[d] ${body.toString()}")
        val res = async { service.doSomething(body.value) }

        return@coroutineScope ResponseEntity.ok(res)
    }
}
```

One of them work normally, one not. Difference is in parameters, working method have requestparam, failed gets param through body.

```
printf "\nworking go"

curl -i -X POST \
   -H "tenant:properTenant" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 'http://localhost:8080/working?param=123'

printf "\nfailed go"

curl -i -X POST \
   -H "tenant:properTenant" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d \
'{"value":21312}' \
 'http://localhost:8080/failed'
```

```
working returns
"param = 123 and tenant was = properTenant"

failed returns
"param = 21312 and tenant was = default"
```

How to get tenant value from /failed method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with Kotlin to give a concrete example, but you shouldn't use ThreadLocal or InheritableThreadLocal in a flux application, since you don't have a dedicated thread per request as in a traditional web application. This is likely why you are getting unexpected results.

Consider using the Context as described [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context).